# How to sort CSV data with Powershell?

Tags: linux, powershell, sorting, sort-object

Once a `CSV` file is loaded, as below, how is the data then sorted?

```
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> $words = Import-Csv -Path ./sort.csv
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> $words                              

symbol code word  morse code phonetic
------ ---------  ---------- --------
A      Alfa/Alpha ● ▬        AL FAH
B      Bravo      ▬ ● ● ●    BRAH VOH
C      Charlie    ▬ ● ▬ ●    CHAR LEE
D      Delta      ▬ ● ●      DELL TAH
E      Echo       .●         ECK OH
F      Foxtrot    ● ● ▬ ●    FOKS TROT
G      Golf       ▬ ▬ ●      GOLF
Z      Zulu       ▬ ▬ ▬ ▬ ▬  ZOO LOO
H      Hotel      ● ● ● ●    HOH TELL
I      India      ● ●        IN DEE AH
J      Juliett    ● ▬ ▬ ▬    JEW LEE ETT
K      Kilo       ▬ ● ▬      KEY LOH
L      Lima       ● ▬ ● ●    LEE MAH
M      Mike       ▬ ▬        MIKE
N      November   ▬ ●        NO VEMBER
O      Oscar      ▬ ▬ ▬      OSS CAH
I      India      ● ●        IN DEE AH
P      Papa       ● ▬ ▬ ●    PAH PAH
Q      Quebec     ▬ ▬ ● ▬    KEH BECK
S      Sierra     ● ● ●      SEE AIRRAH
R      Romeo      ● ▬ ●      ROW ME OH
T      Tango      ▬          TANG OH
U      Uniform    ● ● ▬      YOU NEE FORM
V      Victor     ● ● ● ▬    VIK TAH
W      Whiskey    ● ▬ ▬      WISS KEY
X      X-ray      ▬ ● ● ▬    ECKS RAY
Y      Yankee     ▬ ▬ ● ●    YANG KEY
Z      Zulu       ▬ ▬ ▬ ▬ ▬  ZOO LOO

PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> $words | sort 'code word'           
/usr/bin/sort: cannot read: 'code word': No such file or directory
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> sort $words              
/usr/bin/sort: cannot read: '@{symbol=A; code word=Alfa/Alpha; morse code=● ▬; phonetic=AL FAH}': No such file or directory
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> help sort
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv>
```

see also:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-sort-csv-files-in-order/

which has similar examples, except that the data is sorted as its imported.

---

original data as:

```
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell/csv$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell/csv$ head sort.csv 
symbol,code word,morse code,phonetic
A,Alfa/Alpha,● ▬,AL FAH
B,Bravo,▬ ● ● ●,BRAH VOH
C,Charlie,▬ ● ▬ ●,CHAR LEE
D,Delta,▬ ● ●,DELL TAH
E,Echo,.●,ECK OH
F,Foxtrot,● ● ▬ ●,FOKS TROT
G,Golf,▬ ▬ ●,GOLF
Z,Zulu,▬ ▬ ▬ ▬ ▬,ZOO LOO
H,Hotel,● ● ● ●,HOH TELL
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell/csv$
```

which was copy/pasted from a website.

---

get members shows:

```
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> $words = Import-Csv -Path ./sort.csv
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> $words | Get-Member                 

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
code word   NoteProperty string code word=Alfa/Alpha
morse code  NoteProperty string morse code=● ▬
phonetic    NoteProperty string phonetic=AL FAH
symbol      NoteProperty string symbol=A

PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv>
```

which is as expected.

Comment: Is your `csv` file really a `csv` file? What does `$Words | Get-Member` return ? Please share your input (`csv`) file by pasting it (or the first few lines) into the question.

Comment: I added the head of the file and included `get-members` output @iRon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`sort`** is an external command (Application) on Linux systems.
In other words, do not use the short name (<strike>`sort`</strike>) but the full cmdlet name [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object):

```
$Words |Sort-Object 'code word'
```

As commented by [**@postanote**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9132707/postanote), details about the command precedence can be found in [about_Command_Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence?view=powershell-7). Reading this, might actually look confusing as the process is defined to occur in this order: **`Alias, Function, Cmdlet, any external command/script`** (which should give the **alias** precedence over the **external command** `sort`).
Apparently the `sort` alias is simply not installed on Linux systems (presumably to prevent it from overruling the external native Linux command):

#### Windows (10)

```
Get-Command sort

CommandType     Name                                       Version    Source
-----------     ----                                       -------    ------
Alias           sort -> Sort-Object
```

#### Linux (Pi OS)

```
Get-Command sort

CommandType     Name                                       Version    Source
-----------     ----                                       -------    ------
Application     sort                                       0.0.0.0    /usr/bin/sort
```

This means that you might also resolve this issue by manually overruling the external `sort` command with a `sort` alias:

```
Set-Alias sort Sort-Object
```

Comment: To provide further details, to what iROn's helpful answer, when processing in see [about_Command_Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence?view=powershell-7). Process occurs in this order, `Alias, Function, Cmdlet, any external command/script`. The first match wins.